# How to change the value that a method is returning (JavaScript OOP)

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make a game in JavaScript using OOP and html5 canvas.
I can not move on with the game beacuse I'm stuck in one place.
My question is how can I change the value of method xPosition that is returning a value from a function.
Below you find some code.

```
var myObject = {
    //placing object in start position 
    xPosition : function(){
         return Canvas.width / 2;
    },
    //if keycode pressed move myObject to the left
    move : function(){
         xPosition -= 10; //I know this wont work
    }
};
```

Comment: +1 Don't think you deserved the downvote

Comment: thx skyfoot, i was suprised with the downvote i recived earlier.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change the return values without changing (ie. overwriting) the `xPosition` method itself.

However, you can easily get a value and then change that:

```
… move: function(){
     var xval = this.xPosition();
     xval -= 10; // this works, reassigning to the "xval" variable (xval=xval-10)

     // or in one step:
     var xval = this.xPosition() - 10;
}
```

---

Or you change the input value of the function. Let it compute the current position from canvas size and a relative position stored in a variable (or easier: in a property) and then change only that variable/property from the `move` function:

```
var myObject = {
    // placing object in start position
    xPos: 0,
    getXPosition: function() { // compute value from canvas and position
         return Canvas.width / 2 + this.xPos; // or something similar
    },
    move : function() {
         // change relative position
         this.xPos -= 10;
    }
};
```

Comment: i think the xPosition function has to be a recursion function in this situation if I want to overwrite it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually want to do. What is the `xPosition` function supposed to do? Seems like a simple property would fit better.

Comment: the xPosition is returning the X-Axis coordinates and with this position i'm placing the object on the canvas. When i want to move it than i have to change the X-Axis coordinates.aAsimple number as a value for this would be the easiest way, but what i I want to change the canvas size, than the number is differen. It sill would not make much job to change some values there and there but i thoug i would do it in a function.

Comment: ok but, I'm using this code to draw myObject on cavnas:
Canvas.context.fillRect(this.xPosition(), this.yPosition(), this.width, this.height);
this.xPosition needs to have a start position value and when moved another value. How to change it when xPosition is a function that return a value, can not figure it out, for now i will stay with a simple property.

Answer (score 1):

You need to reference the correct scope of the object. The this keyword will reference the myObject scope.

You are also calling a function so need to add the brackets.

Your other issue is that you are calling a function and trying to update the value. You either need to assign xPosition as a variable or pass in the new value.

```
    move : function(){
         this.xPosition(-10); 
    }
```

Have a look at these articles in structuring javascript

1. [Part 1](http://blog.pluralsight.com/2012/09/18/structuring-javascript-code-part-i/)
2. [Part 2](http://blog.pluralsight.com/2012/09/25/the-prototype-pattern-structuring-javascript-code-part-ii/)
3. [Part 3](http://blog.pluralsight.com/2012/10/02/revealing-module-pattern-structuring-javascript-code-part-iii/)
4. [Part 4](http://blog.pluralsight.com/2012/10/09/revealing-prototype-pattern-structuring-javascript-code-part-iv/)

If you are dealing with x,y positions and as you say you are making a game, I would use vectors to manage your game objects. The vecotr library will handle all the maths for you. Adding, subtracting, multiplying etc.

There are a lot of vector libraries out there or you can build your own.
[Vector Maths](http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/vector-maths-a-primer-for-games-programmers/)

Comment: This is also not working beacuse I'm referring to the xPosition funciton while creating a rectangle (this is the myObject). //Canvas.context.fillRect(this.xPosition(), this.yPosition(), this.width, this.height); this is giving me an error: Property 'xPosition' of object #<Object> is not a function

Comment: check it now, I eddited my code and added the code. hope this helps.

Comment: Please do not link to Google redirects.